# How do I change column type in Apex 20.1 from varchar to float?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I imported a Excel spreadsheet into Apex 20.1.  Several of my columns were formatted as currency eg. $30 but they've all been imported as varchar.  Many of the cells were empty so maybe that's why it didn't automatically recognise the column type.

There didn't seem to be a way to alter the table definition before it loaded the data either.

To change it back to a numeric type ( ? float ), do I need to add another column, import the data from the original column recast as float, delete the first column and then rename the new column back to the original name?

I also want to truncate some varchar(4000) down to varchar(100) but that's another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If column looked exactly like `$30`, then yes - it is a string, not a number, so Oracle created a `VARCHAR2` column. If you removed formatting in Excel *before* doing anything with Apex, it would have been a `NUMBER`.

Now, yes - as you said:

- create a new column
- update table and set new column to numeric value of the old column
- drop the old column
- rename new column to the "old/original" name

Or, alternatively (from point #3)

- empty the old column
- modify its datatype
- move data back into it
- drop the new column

---

As of truncating `varchar2(4000)` column to `(100)`: first shorten its contents to 100 characters, then modify its datatype:

```
update your_table set that_column = substr(that_column, 1, 100);
alter your_table modify that_column varchar2(100);
```

---

Because of such problems, I prefer to

- precreate the target table (using `create table` command), specifying each column's datatype as I want it to be
- load file contents into such a table

Comment: I did what I said I'd do and that worked. Good tip about precreating the table definition.